# How do I set a xlim and ylim on PartialDependenceDisplay?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

```
def partial_2d(model, data, features, xlim=None, ylim=None):
    print('Computing partial dependence plots...')
    tic = time()
    display = PartialDependenceDisplay.from_estimator(model, data, features,n_jobs=-1, grid_resolution=100)
    fig = plt.gcf()
    ax = plt.gca()


    # Adjust scales
    ax.set_xlim([xlim[0], xlim[1]])
    ax.set_ylim([ylim[0], ylim[1]])
    
    print(ax.get_xlim())
    print(ax.get_ylim())
    plt.title('2D-partial dependency plot')

    #fig.subplots_adjust(left=1, bottom=1, right=2, top=2, wspace=0, hspace=0)
    #fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.4, hspace=0.3)
    output_path = os.path.join(subfolder_path, "Graph")
    os.makedirs(output_path, exist_ok=True)

    fig.savefig(os.path.join(output_path,'partial2d {}.png'.format(str(features)+'_'+date_time )), dpi=ImageQuality)
    print("Done in {:.3f}s".format(time() - tic))
    plt.show()
```

```
partial_2d(model = rf_model, data = X, features = [(2,9)], xlim = (0,0.2), ylim = (0,1))
```

The plot having some weird spaces:

[image: The plot having some weird spaces]

The original plot:

[image: The original plot]

As you can see in the image, there is only the (0,0.2) area that shows differences. So I wanted to see only that, and clearly.
And I also want to remove the weird lines on the left and bottom.

Comment: Bruh I just realized that the xlim and ylim does work, but the wierd lines are still there.